# Ninject sharing dependencies or cloning kernel

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a kernel with multiple bindings of, let's say, `ISomeInjectableModule`.

In common situation I am satisfied with receiving my `ISomeInjectableModule[]` through my kernel but there are cases when I need to resolve some additional `ISomeInjectableModule`s along with that already registered in kernel.

I can't just add bindings and remove them after resolving because my kernel is used in several threads and code in neighbor thread should not receive that particular dependencies.

First thing that I have in my mind is that just clone current Kernel (or just a set of bindings from it), to a new one, add additional deps, and then resolve them. If this is correct approach how may I do it properly?

Comment: Two kernels seems like not such a great idea. Sounds like you need [contextual bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)... `Bind<ISomeInjectableModule>().To<SomeConcreteModule>().WhenInjectedInto<ISomethingThatRequiresTheInjectableModule>()`. Any use?